# Display a custom 404 page without a redirect

Tags: templates, redirect, page-template, 404-error, get-template-part

In a plugin I want to display a specific page without redirecting (and thus without changing the URL) like the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/404page/ does. I can capture 404s and redirect them, but I want the URL to stay the same when I show a custom page.

```
// A. this only displays the content and the not the header, footer, or title.
$post = get_page_by_path('/some-page/');
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
```

...

```
// B. This only displays the page template, but doesn't include the content.
$template = get_template_part('page');
echo $template;
```

...

```
// C. A combination of the two doesn't include the sidebar or the or the page title.
$template = get_template_part('header', 'custom-404-page');
echo $template;
$post = get_page_by_path('/custom-page/');
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
$template = get_template_part('footer', 'custom-404-page');
echo $template;
```

... I also tried:

```
// D.
global $post;
$post = get_page_by_path('/custom-404-page/');
setup_postdata($post);
$template = get_template_part('page');
echo $template;
```

but the content of the page still doesn't appear in the basic page template.

thanks

Comment: Any reason not to just use `add_rewrite_rule()`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that but it looks like I would need to know what URL the user requested ahead of time.

Comment: You want a different page to be served when they type in a page your plugin is on? Like served normally with nothing different?

Comment: @tmdesigned That's been my assumption....

Comment: You can use regular expressions in the rewrite rules. So you just need one that matches everything. Something like `add_rewrite_rule('.*', 'index.php?pagename=custom-404', 'top');` Note the rewrite rules need to be flushed after this is done, so you would do the add and flush once, when the plugin is activated. Also, this assumes WordPress knows about the page you're redirecting to.

Comment: It is for 404s. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Yesterday I had it redirecting to `404.php`. Less sure about some special `custom-404.php` page. But it would be more natural to make a child theme and add a customized 404 page to it.

Comment: I've experimented with add_rewrite_rule() a bit and so far it seems pretty complicated. The plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/404page/ displays a specific page without updating .htaccess somehow...